# Fetch the screenshots of app from google play store

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-play

I tried this api https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper but it does not return the screenshots url of a app.Can anyone  suggest the same api for javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, just `npm install request cheerio`. Note that is async, so you would probably want to put it in a promise or similar.

```
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
var request = require("request");

var baseUrl = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=";
var app = "com.spotify.music"; 

function getScreenShots(html) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    var $img = $(".thumbnails img.screenshot");
    var images = [];
    $img.each(function() {
        images.push($(this).attr("src"));
    });
    console.log(images);
}

function getReviews(html) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    var $allReviews = $(".single-review");
    var reviews = [];
    $allReviews.each(function() {
        var rating = $(".review-info-star-rating > div", $(this)).attr("aria-label");
        var review = {
            "author": $(".author-name", $(this)).text(),
            "date": $(".review-date", $(this)).text(),
            "rating": rating.match(/([12345]){1}/)[0] + "/5",
            "comment": $(".review-body", $(this)).text()
        }
        reviews.push(review);
    });
    console.log(reviews);
}

request(baseUrl + app, function(error, response, body) {
    getScreenShots(body);
    getReviews(body);
});
```

Comment: In same way we can get the user reviews?

Comment: sure, I've updated my answer with a review example as well.